# Match Entire String in MS Word Search

Tags: microsoft-word, regex, search, wildcards

I want to return a citation string using wild card search in MS Word. The citations are superscript, so it is easy to isolate them from other text. The search requirements are:

- Numbers can be any length
- Citation can have commas or dashes
- I want to return **only the whole string** so I can surround it with a
  delimiter (|)

**Examples**

6,7,11,16

1

4,5-7,810,12-32,2

The following Word wildcard term will correctly find the string, but then continues to return all of the sub-strings within the result. I need it to continue the search after finding the entire string:

```
[0-9\-,]{1,}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To surround such strings with a delimiter in Find field use (in your case you will probably use comma instead of semicolon - this is a regional setting):

```
([0-9\-,]{1;})
```

In Replace field:

```
|\1|
```

Just tested. Works on your example.

Comment: Thanks a ton - appreciate the help!